Being explicit about the kernel of the map $R[x]\to \frac{R}{I}[x]$ . coefficients of $\frac{R}{I}[x]$ and commutative diagrams
The following is taken from Introduction to Abstract Algebra From Rings, Numbers, Groups, and Fields to Polynomials and Galois Theory by:  Benjamin Fine, Anthony M. Gaglione, and Gerhard Rosenberger, Algebra Notes from the underground by: Paolo Aluffi
Background
Exercsie:  Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$, and consider the subset $I[x]$ of $R[x]$ consisting of those polynomials whose coefficients belong to $I$.  Prove that $I[x]$ is an ideal of $R[x]$ and that $\frac{R[x]}{I[x]}\backsimeq(\frac{R}{I})[x]$; meaning that the map $f:\Bbb{R}[x]\to (\frac{R}{I})[x]$ given by $f(\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(r_i+I)x^i$ is an epimorphism and its kernel is $I[x]$.
From Aluffi

The natural projection $\tau:R\to \frac{R}{I}$ is a surjective ring homomorphism; therefore we have a surjective ring homomorphism $f:\Bbb{R}[x]\to (\frac{R}{I})[x]$, defined by applying $\tau$ to the coefficients of a polynomial.  Note that
$\text{ker }f=\{\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i\mid\forall i,\tau(r_i)=0_R\}= \{\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i\mid\forall i,r_i\in I\}=I[x]$

Questions
I want to ask about how to write out explicitly the kernel of the map $f$ in set builder notation and what it means for the map to have kernel $f$, meaning what it means for $f(\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i)=0_{(\frac{R}{I})[x]}$, and also a quick question about commutative diagram for the map $f$.
When we are given a homomorphic map $\varphi:A\to B$ of rings $A,B$, the kernel of $\varphi$ is the set $\text{ker }\varphi=\{a\in A\mid\varphi(a)=0_B\}$. Letting $\varphi=\tau, A=R, B=\frac{R}{I}$ and since $r_i+I=0+I=I$, and $Ix^i\subset I$, then for the map $f(\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(r_i+I)x^i$ to equal to $0_{(\frac{R}{I})[x]}$, the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(r_i+I)x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(0_R+I)x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}Ix^i\subset \sum_{i=0}^{n}I\subset I$, but it should an element of $I[x]$ instead.
So the kernel of $f$ should be writtten as:  $\text{ker }f=\{\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i\in \Bbb{R}[x]\mid\forall i,\tau(r_i)=0_R\}= \{\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i\mid\forall i,r_i\in I\}=I[x]$
Lastly, the map $f:\Bbb{R}[x]\to (\frac{R}{I})[x]$ should satisfy the following commutative diagram with maps $p,q$ implicitly given.
$$\begin{array}{cc} R & \xrightarrow{\tau} & R/I& \\
\small\textit{p}\big\downarrow &  & \big\downarrow\small\textit{q}   \\
R[x] & \xrightarrow{f} & (\frac{R}{I})[x] &  &  \end{array}$$
Thank you in advance

Note that $Ix^i\neq I$. The fact that the class of a polynomial lies in $\sum_{i}(0_R+I)x^i$ is equivalent to all coefficients of that polynomial being in $I$, which is equivalent to the polynomial being an element of $I[x]$.

@Mastrem I edited my post according to your comment.  Can you also elaborate more in math notation about "equivalent to all coefficients of that polynomial being in $I$, which is equivalent to the polynomial being an element of $[]$, especially about the last part "...equivalent to the polynomial being an element of $[]"$.  I am having trouble showing that especially when trying to compute the kernel.

Math notation doesn't necessarily make this more precise or more readable than using a bit of natural language. Let $P:=\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i$ be a polynomial, then $f(P)=\sum_{i=0}^n\tau(r_i)x^i$, per definition of $f$. Therefore, $f(P)=0$ if and only if $\tau(r_i)=0$ for all $0\le i\le n$. Now, $\tau(r_i)=0$ is equivalent to $r_i\in I$, so $f(P)=0$ if and only if $r_i\in I$ for all $0\le i\le n$, which, per definition, is equivalent to $P\in I[x]$. Therefore, $f(P)=0$ if and only if $P\in I[x]$. So $\ker(f)=I[x]$.

In set builder notation, which is a lot less readable, this is
$$
\begin{align*}
\ker(f) &= \left{\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i:f\left(\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i\right)=0\right}\
&=\left{\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i:\sum_{i=0}^n\tau(r_i)x_i=0\right}\
&=\left{\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i:\forall 0\le i\le n(\tau(r_i)=0)\right}\
&=\left{\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i:\forall 0\le i\le n(r_i\in I)\right}\
&=I[x].
\end{align*}
$$

@Mastrem how you have written the kernel of $f$, do I have to explicitly include $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_ix^i\in \Bbb{R}[x]$?  Also, is the commutative diagram I included correct about the map $f$?  I hope I am not trying to be ultra pedantic.  I am not at the state of my learning where I feel that I can afford to skip details, however smalll they might be.

You didn't specify the maps $p,q$, but if they are the usual embeddings, then the diagram does indeed commute. And sure, you could specify that $\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix_i\in R[x]$ in the set builder notation, but it is also clear from context. Also, $\mathbb{R}$ is used only for the field of real numbers, not for any ring. And finally, my comment right above the one which uses set builder notation is just as precise, but a lot more readable. I would really recommend that style over only using set builder notation, even if you are still learning.

The map $f$ is given by the universal property of polynomials applied to $q\circ \tau.$ There is only one map that sends $x$ to $x$ and makes the diagram commute.

@Keplerto how come when students learn about evaluation map homomorphism in a standard Abstract Algebra course, the above commutative diagram is not shown?

I don't know, perhaps it depends on the course. For example the general form does appear here. https://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_21.pdf.

@Keplerto thank you for the reference.
